# Are the EnterpriseLibrary.Caching components discontinued, and, if so, as of which library version?

Tags: enterprise-library

I'm looking at some old code that relies on

```
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching
```

As far as I can tell, the namespace doesn't exist in the latest version of the EnterpriseLibrary. Is this correct? If so, when did the components get discontinued?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enterprise Library 6.0 removed the Caching block, as well as the Security block and Cryptography.

All caching should now be performed with System.Runtime.Caching.

A good read is the Enterprise Library 6 patterns and practices free book.

[Enterprise Library 6 Developers Guide](https://download.microsoft.com/download/D/2/0/D204F45F-4B44-4A0D-BC08-F9FA10BA0896/Developer's%20Guide%20to%20Microsoft%20Enterprise%20Library%20-%202nd%20Edition.pdf)

Comment: The page you posted is no longer valid... Is System.Runtime.Caching  supposed to be the replacement or they are totally different implementations?

Comment: System.Runtime.Caching is the replacement.  They basically made the EL caching block a first class citizen in the framework.  I'll update the link